# ffprobe stream selection for encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, ffprobe

when I run ffmpeg, I can see "default" audio and video stream:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 3859 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc 
  (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-05-03 22:50:47
  handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 92 kb/s 
  (default)
 Metadata:
  creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 675x1000 [SAR 72:72 DAR 27:40], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

As I understand, this stream selected by ffmpeg as input when encoding, if map option not set.

How can I get "default" stream using ffprobe ?

Sorry for English